# ffmpeg output cannot be opened by macos quicktime

Tags: ffmpeg, quicktime

So simply

I run

```
ffmpeg -i my_stack.mp4 -vcodec h264 -acodec aac -strict -2 out_video.mov
```

I have the output file `out_video.mov`

I then try to open it with quicktime player and get

```
The file isn’t compatible with QuickTime Player.
```

Someone know what command I should run to fix this?

Comment: Without seeing the console output, I can only guess it's due to an unsupported pixel format, so try adding `-pix_fmt yuv420p`